# Behat 2.5 with Drupal 7 - Restart scenario execution when step fails

Tags: drupal-7, behat

I have a case when a test step in a scenario fails with a spin timeout. This happens randomly as the next time this scenario runs, the case passes. So I wrote a @AfterStep `handleSpinErrors(StepEvent $event)` custom function in FeatureContext that checks if the step fails because of a spin timeout. I am able to get the conditions right, but I am not sure how to execute the scenario again from within this function.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the behat build-in `--rerun` feature? http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html